# Qual a forma correta de declarar um encadeamento de métodos e impedir que um mesmo método seja usado fora de escopo?

Tags: c#, linq, arquitetura-de-software, design-pattern, herança

Nas minhas últimas perguntas estava criando alguns métodos para automatizar algumas consultas. Está legal, mas agora preciso controlar o acesso aos métodos especificando uma sequência.

Ao usar o método **Select()**, eu não posso ter acesso à ele novamente. Após o método Where() eu não posso ter acesso aos métodos **LeftJoin()** e **InnerJoin()**. Isso até que se chegue definitivamente ao método **ToList()**;

Minha classe funcionará criando comandos sql´s de forma encadeada como o Linq to Lambda.

Assim:

```
var pessoas = pessoaDAO.Select()
    .LeftJoin(x => x.Telefones, (telefones, pessoa) => telefones.PessoaId == pessoa.Id)
    .Where(x => x.Ativo)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Nome)
    .ToList();
```

Seria errado permitir isso:

```
var pessoas = pessoaDAO
    .Select(x => 
        x.Id, 
        x => x.Pessoa, 
        x => x.Ativo,
        x => x.Telefones)
    .Where(x => x.Ativo)
    .Select()
    .ToList();
```

Ou seja, um **Select()** após um **Where()** e até mesmo um **Select()** já ter sido chamado.

Para resolver essa questão, estou tentando separar os métodos por interface. Assim:

```
public interface IQueryBuilder<TModel> : ICustomQueryBuilder<TModel>
    where TModel : class
{
    ICustomQueryBuilder<TModel> Select();
    ICustomQueryBuilder<TModel> Select(params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] members);
}

public interface ICustomQueryBuilder<TModel> : 
    IQueryBuilderJoin<TModel>, 
    IQueryBuilderFilter<TModel>, 
    IQueryBuilderOrder<TModel>, 
    IQueryBuilderExecute<TModel>
    where TModel : class
{        
}
```

**IQueryBuilder** que será a interface usada para implementar minha classe herda de **ICustomQueryBuilder**, e os métodos **Select()** devolvem o tipo ICustomQueryBuilder para que então eu não possa ter acesso ao método **Select()** novamente.

**IQueryBuilder** herda de ICustomQueryBuilder e esta das demais interfaces porque preciso ter um tipo implementado na classe para fazer o retorno.

Já, **ICustomQueryBuilder** herda de:

```
public interface IQueryBuilderJoin<TModel> : 
    IQueryBuilderFilter<TModel>, 
    IQueryBuilderOrder<TModel>, 
    IQueryBuilderExecute<TModel>
    where TModel : class
{
    IQueryBuilderJoin<TModel> LeftJoin<TMemberJoin>(
        Expression<Func<TModel, TMemberJoin>> member, 
        Expression<Func<TMemberJoin, TModel, bool>> filter);

    IQueryBuilderJoin<TModel> LeftJoin<TMemberJoin>(
        Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TMemberJoin>>> member, 
        Expression<Func<TMemberJoin, TModel, bool>> filter);

    IQueryBuilderJoin<TModel> InnerJoin<TMemberJoin>(
        Expression<Func<TModel, TMemberJoin>> member, 
        Expression<Func<TMemberJoin, TModel, bool>> filter);

    IQueryBuilderJoin<TModel> InnerJoin<TMemberJoin>(
        Expression<Func<TModel, IEnumerable<TMemberJoin>>> member, 
        Expression<Func<TMemberJoin, TModel, bool>> filter);
}
```

Em sequência de:

```
public interface IQueryBuilderFilter<TModel> : IQueryBuilderOrder<TModel>
    where TModel : class
{
    IQueryBuilderFilter<TModel> Where(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> filter);
}

public interface IQueryBuilderOrder<TModel> : IQueryBuilderExecute<TModel>
    where TModel : class
{
    IQueryBuilderOrder<TModel> OrderBy(params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] members);
    IQueryBuilderOrder<TModel> OrderByDesc(params Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] members);
}

public interface IQueryBuilderExecute<TModel>
    where TModel : class
{
    List<TModel> ToList();
}
```

Por fim, teria:

```
public class QueryBuilder<TModel> : IQueryBuilder<TModel>
    where TModel : class
{
   // ... implementações
}
```

**É correto fazer esse tipo de implementação?**

Para ilustrar melhor a necessidade do retorno, exemplo:

```
public class PessoaDAO : GenericDAO<Pessoa>
{
    // ... outros métodos

    public IQueryBuilderFilter<Pessoa> Where(Expression<Func<TModel, bool>> filter)
    {
       // ... implementações
       return this;
    }

    // ... outros métodos 
}
```

Ou seja, isso é necessário para o encadeamento dos métodos e o tipo deve ser um tipo já implementado, caso contrário o cast automático não será aceito.

Comment: A segregação de interfaces é uma boa prática de modelagem OO. Aplicar isso na construção de DSL é muito interessante. Vários frameworks usam a técnica e eu mesmo usei algumas vezes. Dependendo da complexidade da solução é interessante fazer um diagrama de estados para ilustrar o comportamento. Com cada estado representando uma interface você poderá deixar bem claro através de setas quais os métodos que continuam na mesma interface (estado) e quais causam a transição para um novo estado sem volta. Também poderá ver nisso se o código atende tudo o que precisa e se está coerente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## É correto fazer esse tipo de implementação?

Do ponto de vista apenas do objetivo da implementação, sim. Aliás, eu diria que esta é a forma performática (elegante) de permitir ou não o encadeamento dos métodos.

Entretanto, considero que essa organização possa caracterizar uma perda de funcionalidade. Não há nada de errado em permitir um `OrderBy()` depois de um `Where()`, ou um `Where()` depois de um `Select()`. Entendo que a normatização serve para deixar o conjunto dos métodos de extensão o mais parecido com uma linguagem SQL ANSI, mas a ideia dos métodos de extensão não é se aproximar do SQL: a ideia é trabalhar com a manipulação agnóstica de conjuntos.

Comment: OrderBy() depois de um Where(), ou um Where() depois de um Select(), ok. Mas eu apresentei um Select().Where().Select().. isso que disse não ser legal. Obrigado!

Comment: @user18098 Por que? Não é SQL.

Comment: Não é SQL mas é para criar. Só para o que quero acho não ser interessante.

Comment: Obrigado! Até...